# How to show user's friends posts

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, webapp2

I am working on a webapp in which user can post and share among friends like on facebook or other social media and user's homepage will contain all of his friends post. for saving users and their friends i am using datastore. code for the same is:

```
class Tour(db.Model):
 username = db.StringProperty()
 userid = db.StringProperty()
 dst = db.StringProperty()
 frm = db.StringProperty()
 via = db.StringProperty()
 desc = db.TextProperty()
 date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

`class User(db.Model):
  google_user_id = db.StringProperty()
  google_display_name = db.StringProperty()
class Friends(db.Model):
 owner_user_id = db.StringProperty()
 friend_user_id = db.StringProperty()
 friends_name = db.StringProperty()`
```

For storing users friends, my code is:

```
 `@staticmethod
  def get_and_store_friends(user):
    http = decorator.http()
    user = service.people().get(userId="me").execute(http=http)
    edges = Friends.all().filter('owner_user_id = ', user['id']).run()
    db.delete(edges)
    friends =service.people().list(userId='me',collection='visible').execute(http=http)
    for google_friend in friends.get('items'):
     friend_id = google_friend.get('id')
     friend_name = google_friend.get('displayName')
     friend = User.all().filter('google_user_id = ',google_friend.get('id')).get()
     if friend is not None:
      edge = Friends()
      edge.owner_user_id = user['id']
      edge.friend_user_id = friend_id
      edge.friends_name = friend_name
      edge.put()`
```

I need help in querying datastore to retrieve post of user's friends. 
I tried by this:

```
  friend_already = Friends.all().filter('owner_user_id =',user['id']).get()
  if friend_already is not None:
    friend_id = friend_already.friend_user_id
    friend_tour = Tour.all().filter('userid =',friend_id)
    friends_tour = friend_tour.fetch(100)
```

but it is returning only one friend's post. How to query from datastore to get all post of a user's friend.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.get()` in your friend_already line only returns the first one.

To get all the friends use:

```
friend_already = Friends.all().filter('owner_user_id =',user['id'])  # no get()
for each in friend_already:
    friend_id = each.friend_user_id
    ....
```